# Mostrar campo de texto no editable dependiendo del rol ASP.NET

Tags: html5, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET en una aplicación web y el tipo de usuario que puede ingresar son dos: *ADMINISTRADOR* y *USUARIO*. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se ingrese al sistema, dependiendo del usuario, estén habilitados algunos inputtext. Por ejemplo, si el usuario es administrador que estén habilitados todos los inputtext pero si es un usuario normal estén deshabilitados todos.

Este es el código del formulario donde están los campos que quiero que no sean editables. Dentro de este formulario no quiero que sean editables los tres primeros campos: *Matricula*, *Nombre completo* y *Email*

```
<form id="informacionUsuario" class="contact-form">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                                <select name="area" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                                <select name="ubicacion" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
     @if(User.IsInRole("ADMIN")){
          <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" />
     }else{
          <input type="text" disabled name="matricula" class="form-control" />
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" @if(User.IsInRole("ADMINISTRADOR")){ disable }/>
```