# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017

Amigos soy nuevo en .NET y empecé a trabajar con ASP.NET en Visual Studio 2017 y he tenido un problemita al ejecutar el siguiente javascript para los usuarios que tengan rol

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

        var role = @HttpContext.Current.Session["typeUser"].ToString();

   switch (role){
    case "usuario" :
           document.getElementByName("Matricula").disabled = true;
           document.getElementByName("Nombre").disabled = true;
   break;
}

    </script>
```

El error esta ocurriendo en la linea 19

```
var role = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["typeUser"].ToString()';
```

**Descripción:** Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

El error es el siguiente al ejecutar la aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Información de versión:**

Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; 
Versión ASP.NET:4.7.3429.0

**Stacktrace**

```
[NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.]
   ASP._Page_Views_RegistroTicket_FormTicket_cshtml.<Execute>b__3_0() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Views\RegistroTicket\FormTicket.cshtml:20
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<RenderSection>b__0(TextWriter tw) +316
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:39
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer) +232
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +237
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9873649
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Comment: Tu objeto sesion no esta inicializado es decir parece que tu usuario no esta firmado por lo que al convertir ToString no existe y te envia la excepcion.

Comment: Sabes como puedo setear o inicializar el valor de sesion para que no me envie la excepcion

Comment: Una session de usuario se inicializa cuando un usuario se logea, es decir su usuario y password son validos, ahora ya existe en mvc el uso de credenciales en tu aplicacion, tu para que usuaras esos valores para autorizar algun permiso en los controladores?

Comment: Para cargar ciertos campos de texto dependiendo del rol de usuario

Comment: Bueno primero crea una aplicacion donde se pueda autenticar, autorizar este [ejemplo](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/custom-authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-mvc) te da una idea, despues comienzas por crear vistas parciales para cada tipo de usuario.

Comment: Realmente no tengo que crear vistas, esa ya la tengo, requiero que la misma vista sea visible para todos los usuarios pero dependiendo del rol se habilite ciertos campos así como se pregunta aqui [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275137/mostrar-campo-de-texto-no-editable-dependiendo-del-rol-asp-net ] pero si necesito hacerlo con variables de sesion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95505/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-miguel-zarate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coloca el stacktrace para saber quien dispara el null.
Los mas probables es que no esté seteado el valor de sesión "typeUser" y cuando hace el ".ToString()" explota.

Otro error que vas a tener es en javascript, debés colocar así:

```
var role = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["typeUser"].ToString()';
```

Comment: Revisa nuevamente la pregunta ya se coloco el stacktrace, y tambien realice la modificacion de la linea de javascript sigue el mismo error